# NPM global packages not available on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-modules

**MY SITUATION**

I have installed version Node v6.2.0 using **n** on Ubuntu 14.04. It's located under path **/usr/local/n/versions/node/6.2.0** (by using *npm prefix -g*).

My global packages installs in that directory under **lib/node_modules** but I can't use that packages from command line globally.

**NOTE**
Earlier I was using older version Nodejs 5 installed different way. And packages installed globally with that version of Node are available now, but not **new ones** which I installing now.

**MY QUESTION**

Is there a trick or something to point **node_modules** directory from which its packages could be used globally?

Comment: could you clarify more ? stacktrace `node -v ` ? and what is `I have installed version Node v6.2.0 using n` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your global package binaries should be available here:

```
/usr/local/n/versions/node/{NODE VERSION}/bin
```

Add it to your path (in `.bashrc` or `.bashprofile` or `.zshrc`):

```
NPM_GLOBALS=/usr/local/n/versions/node/{NODE VERSION}/bin
PATH=$NPM_GLOBALS:$PATH
```

Then restart your console or just run `source ~/.bashrc`

Also, if you're working with multiple versions of node, I highly recommend [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for installing and managing them.

Comment: Actualy, I have those packages under ``/usr/local/n/versions/node/6.2.0/bin``, so I added as you mentioned to ``.bashrc`` but nothing changed

Comment: Run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Nope, still the same

Comment: Woops. Should be `PATH=$NPM_GLOBALS:$PATH` not `PATH=NPM_GLOBALS:$PATH`.

Comment: Oh....thanks man. But can you explain what is all about? Why should I dance around with setting global paths?

Comment: When you run a command, the paths in your `PATH` variable are searched. If the global binaries aren't in your path, they won't be found. By default, only the system binary directories are in your path (such as `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc). So if you want to run a command without specifying its path and it isn't in one of those directories, you'll have to add it to `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

I simply added `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH` to my .zshrc file.